# CORS multiple origins flagged when only one is specified

Tags: cors, same-origin-policy

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load  The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   contains multiple values but only one is allowed. Origin is therefore
>   not allowed access.

But both origins match, character to character.

Access Control Allow Origin is specified in only one location, the web.config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://ourapp.local.ourdomain.com:8080" />
```

and in the WebApiConfig CORS is enabled:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

There are no other references to CORS in the application. Where do the multiple origins come from and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you remove that `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"…` element from your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

To close this out, it turns out our application was specifying the origin in two locations. I had forgotten about a class library we'd included, that also managed the ALLOW-ORIGIN's origin. It turned out this library was unnecessary and once removed the issue cleared up.